# Unexpected TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (meteor-rxjs)

Tags: meteor, rxjs

I'm getting an exception and don't understand why. The sample code is cut down from the original, but the line in question starts `let subscription=`. This code is within a method so only occurs on the server side.

The failing line within Meteor subscribe():
`return Meteor.subscribe.apply(Meteor, [name].concat(args.concat([{...`

Here's the exception and traceback:

```
Exception while invoking method 'someMethod' TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at subscribe (c:\Build\myapp\node_modules\meteor-rxjs\dist\bundles\index.umd.js:609:36)
at Observable._subscribe (c:\Build\myapp\node_modules\meteor-rxjs\dist\bundles\index.umd.js:628:30)
at ZoneOperator.call (c:\Build\myapp\node_modules\meteor-rxjs\dist\bundles\index.umd.js:695:23)
at Observable.subscribe (c:\Build\myapp\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.js:42:22)
```

Here's my code within a Meteor method:

```
    let list = MyCollection.find(aselector);
    let subscription= MeteorObservable.subscribe("publishedList, selector).zone().subscribe( () => {

      list = MyCollection.find(selector);
      let myArray = list.fetch();
      let item: MyItem = myArray.length > 0? myArray[0]: null;
    });
```

Comment: One doesn't subscribe on the server. There should never be a need for a method to subscribe.

Comment: Aha. I didn't want to assume that the find/findOne was synchronous on the server within the method. But that appears to be required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Meteor method should not contain subscribes, since the collection operations are synchronous in the simple case (no callback). Removing the extra code that came from trying to solve the issue and ignoring edge cases, the code can be simplified to:

```
let item: MyItem = MyCollection.findOne(selector);
```